# Do Vedas have these concepts?

Tags: vedas, vedanta, karma, moksha, rebirth

Karma, Maya, Atman, Brahman, Moksha, Reincarnation and Indriya Nigraha (Sense Control) are they present in Vedic Samhitas? (Not Upanishads only Samhitas)

Comment: Yes and No. Your question is too broad. Make a separate question for each term.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda How sir

Comment: Karma,Maya,Atman,Brahman,Moksha,Reincarnation and Indriya Nigraha(Sence Control) they all are separate topic of discussion. That's why. @Sethu

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Brahman**

> shariram brahma prAvishat |
>
> Brahman has entered this body (AV 11.8.30)

> rucham brAhmam janayantah, devA agre tat abruva, yastu evam brAhmano
> vidyAt, tasya deva asan vashe ||
>
> When the gods got the revelation of knowledge of Brahman they declared
> the teaching about That. That sage who knows the Supreme as described
> before will have sovereignty over Gods (for he has become the Inmost
> Self of all)
>
> (Vajansaneyi Samhita 31.21 of Yajurveda)

**AtmA**

> tameva vidvAn armanam na bi bhaya mrtyoh |
>
> No fear of death for the knower of the Atman. (AV 10.8.44)

> Surya **AtmA** jagatah tasthusha cha |
>
> The (spiritual) Sun is the soul of all that is static and dynamic. (AV
> 13.2.35). (This Mantra is also found in Rig Veda 1.115.1).

The concept of AtmA situated in the lotus of the heart is elaborated in AV 10.8.43 as follows:

> There is a nine-gated lotus, covered under three bands, in which lives
> the Spirit with the Atman within, that the Veda-knowers know.

**Moksha**

Mrityunjaya Mantra of Rig Veda or Purusha Sukta mantras.

**The way how Karma works**

That is if one does good Karma he gets rewarded and if bad Karmas are done then punishments are received in turn.

> yat upari shayanam Aharanti svarga meva tena lokam avarundhe |
>
> He who prepares a good bed for the guest, he indeed reaches heaven (AV
> 9.6.9)

> ramantAm punyA lakshmir, yAh pApih tA aninasham |
>
> The person enjoys who gets his money by honest means, the evil one who
> gets his money by evil means is surely going to be destroyed. (AV
> 7.115.4)

**Indriya Nigraha**

It is part of Tapas (austerity).

> Rohito divam Aruhat tapasA tapasvi |
>
> The person who does *Tapas* mounts the heaven. (AV 13.2.25)

Few more glorifying the power of Tapas:

> By the tapas of brahmacharya, the king protects the state; by the
> tapas of brahmacharya, the acharya seeks his pupil. (AV 11.5.17)
>
> By the tapas of brahmacharya the deva-s drove away death; Indra
> through brahmacharya brought the Supreme Light svar to deva-s. (AV
> 11.5.19)

*(AV denotes Atharva Veda).*

Comment: Sir thanks a lot for answering!Can we get from other Samhitas also?Because few scholars only include 3 Samhitas...Sir are Karma Reincarnation and Maya also present?Maya like Brahman alone is true and world is appearance...in Vedas...Also controlling of sence organs....?

Comment: No problem.. that I have to check. When I saw the question I immediately remembered that I can answer it using Atharva Veda mantras. For the other Vedas references I need to check. @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: For Indriya Nigraha I have given one on Tapas @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: Also Maya is there in Upanishads @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: Sir I have few doubts sir Can you please help me??How to contact you sir??And request you to answer my questions??I could do on Quora but unable to request my answers from you

Comment: Sir Upanishads yes but Prof Lal Mani Joshi has spoilt all my life by his article-You edited tags for my question also-Can you please answer it?

Comment: First off you don't have to call me sir :) You can post questions on this site only. If I know the answer I will answer. If someone else knows the answer they can also answer. So, it's good if you continue posting the questions you have in mind @S

Comment: Sir I want to request your answer to my question sir...in that sence I wanted to contact you...is there any way??

Comment: Don't worry Upanishads are not post Buddhist. But right now I don't have any idea how to answer it. But someone else might. So kindly wait. @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: Thanks a lot Rickross Ji(Since you said not to call sir). If you dont mind could you please come on platforms like Quora and share your knowledge?

Comment: No I don't find that much time. Very sorry about that. But I try to remain active and participating on this site. @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: Ok Rickross Ji no problem. Can I write a comment here itself to request your help on my other answers?

Comment: Yes you can certainly do that. @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: Sir please see this once :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dharmak%C4%81ya
Is this concept identical to Gita Verses 6.30-31?

Comment: How are they identical? Gita 6.30 is here: https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/6/verse/30 @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: Thanks a lot sir but Dhammakaya Tradition(Thailand) say the Dhammakaya is the eternal Buddha within all beings. The dhammakaya is Nibbāna, and is equated with the true Self.Wiki writes that The Dhammakāya tradition of Thailand and the Tathāgatagarbha sūtras of the ancient Indian tradition view the dharmakāya as the ātman (true self) of the Buddha present within all beings. Can you please refer this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddha-nature. Please scroll till end in that page and read "Multiple meanings"

Comment: Okay that's true. Hinduism also says the same that God is within every being @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: Sir isnt it dissapointing?Buddhists claim this philosophy is also copied from them....Please help me sir..How do I say both are different?Earlier I used to focus on these 2 points Atman and Brahman -Buddhism has both....

Comment: In Vedas we find that Brahman has entered the body then how can they claim that? Hinduism is much more ancient than any religion what to say about Buddhism?@SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: They only copied from us na sir?But general view of Buddhism like Thervada etc al reject Atman and Brahman right?

Comment: Yes we can say that they borrowed our concepts. A more respectful way is to say that they taught the same things that are known to Hindus many years ago. Also Buddha is considered as one avatar of Vishnu. So, it is not surprising if we find such similarties between the two teachings @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patient and kind reply Rickross Ji!

Comment: No problem :) @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: @Rickross add for the Maya part also from Mayabheda hymn of RigVeda: पतंगमक्तमसुरस्य मायया हृदा पश्यन्ति मनसा विपश्चितः ।10.177.1 (The wise behold with their mind in their heart the Sun, made manifest by the illusion/Maya of the Asura;) also in AtharvaVeda 8.10.22: 'The Asuras depend for life on Maya'

Answer (score 5):

This is a partial answer.

**Reincarnation and Karma**

> Burn him not up, nor quite consume him, Agni: let not his body or his
> skin be scattered. O Jatavedas, when thou hast matured him, then send
> him on his way unto the Fathers.
>
> When thou hast made him ready, Jatavedas, then do thou give him over
> to the Fathers. When he attains unto the life that waits him, he shall
> become Deities’ controller.
>
> The Sun receive thine eye, the Wind thy spirit; go, **as thy merit is,
> to earth or heaven**. Go, if it be thy lot, unto the waters, go, make
> thine home in plants with all thy members.
>
> Thy portion is the goat: with heat consume him: let thy fierce flame,
> thy glowing splendour, burn him. With thine auspicious forms, o
> Jatavedas, **bear this man to the region of the pious**.
>
> Again, O Agni, to the Fathers send him who, offered in thee, goes with
> our oblations. **Wearing new life let him increase his offspring: let
> him rejoin a body**, Jatavedas.

**Rig Veda X.16.1-5**

**Indra recalls his previous births**

> I was aforetime Manu, I was Sūrya: I am the sage Kakṣīvān, holy
> singer. Kutsa the son of Ārjuni I master. I am the sapient Uśanā
> behold me.

**Rig Veda IV.26.1**

> The Sun receive thine eye, the Wind thy spirit; **go, as thy merit is,
> to earth or heaven.** Go, if it be thy lot, unto the waters, go, make
> thine home in plants with all thy members.

**Rig Veda X.16.3**

**Atman and Brahman**

> 20 Two Birds with fair wings, knit with bonds of friendship, in the
> same sheltering tree have found a refuge. **One of the twain eats the
> sweet Fig-tree’s fruitage;** the other eating not regardeth only.

**Rig Veda I.164.20**

> The tree whereon the fine Birds eat the sweetness, where they all rest
> and procreate their offspring, – Upon its top they say the fig is
> luscious; **none gaineth it who knoweth not the Father**.

**Rig Veda I.164.22**

The bird that eats the sweet fruit is interpreted as the Atman (and also Brahman in Advaita Vedanta). The other bird is the Jiva. The father in 'none gaineth it who knoweth not the Father' is Brahman.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir. Your answers are always beautiful!

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru, no need to call me sir!